# how to take inputs form user based on no of test cases?

Tags: java

hey i got a problem while taking inputs from user recently i wrote coding question in hackerrank in that it ask like first line contains no of test cases and second line (next N lines) contains no of inputs like for eg

```
 2(test cases)
    7
    11
```

for this i wrote code like this

```
int n=sc.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
int p=sc.nextInt();
}
```

hope u understand the problem like how should i store each value in sperate variable here 7 is stored in p variable then i didn't understand like how to store 11 in seperate variable or any other solutions are available?

Comment: this is a java question, not a c question.  Please remove the c tag

Comment: Suggest implementing an array for variable 'p'  Then index into that array via variable 'i'

Comment: without using array is that possible?

Comment: Give your variables proper names. Why do you need to store those values? Why would you rather not use an array? If you just need to generate that output why not do it in the loop? Generally coding quests are out of scope on SU and rather belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: *without using array is that possible*  Yes, anything is possible,  However, being practical would involve an array